# Constant inserts into catalogsearch_result

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.1.0

We have a Magento 1.9.1.0 shop and it's constantly doing this operation:

```
Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 237 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, MATCH (s.data_index)
```

This is crashing the site every day resulting the following error:

```
User X already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

Is this resource related or something else? What could be doing the constant inserts?